# Excel - Increment Cell Reference By 10

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am referencing a cell on another sheet the reference is the following in the B2 spot.

```
=Data!B227
```

I would like to drag down so B3 becomes **=Data!B237** how can I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

In B2:

```
=INDEX(Data!B:B,227+((ROW(1:1)-1)*10))
```

Then drag/copy down